# Reset step count and start calculating step from 0

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have a pedometer which calculates the steps from device sensors perfectly. i want to reset the step count to 0 when move to another activity and starts the stepcount from 0 instead of the earlier stepcount.

I tried to save my initial step count and subtract it from the current sensor data but the steps are not calculating it's showing me only 0 and 1.

Here is my code:

```
Activity1.java 
  private  String Initial_Count_Key = "FootStepInitialCount";  
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
SharedPreferenceManager.singleton().save(Initial_Count_Key,total_step);}
```

Here is my activity2 where I want to reset my steps. I wrote a method for it also but I think I am doing something wrong.

```
Activity2.java
 private void countStep() {

        mIntialSteps = (SharedPreferenceManager.singleton().getInt("FootStepInitialCount"));
        mUpdatedSteps = StepDetector.CURRENT_SETP - mIntialSteps;
        Log.i("Updated_Steps", String.valueOf(mUpdatedSteps));

        if (mUpdatedSteps % 2 == 0) {
            mStepCountValue = mUpdatedSteps;

        } else {
            mStepCountValue = mUpdatedSteps + 1;
        }

        mStepCountValue = mUpdatedSteps ;

    }
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. what exactly "it didn't work for me."

Comment: your `countStep` method is strange, you use a condition to set `mStepCountValue` value then after the `if-esle` set the value again ... ps : you could simply do `mStepCountValue = mUpdatedSteps + mUpdatedSteps%2;`

Comment: @AxelH I know it looks strange but I got this method from github and it was working fine so I used it. But now I am stuck with this step resetting issue.

Comment: @GauravTiwari, there is only one result possible with this code : `mStepCountValue = mUpdatedSteps;`, Check the value of `mIntialSteps` on each count, you probably override somehow or `StepDetector.CURRENT_SETP` is never updated (where is it coming from ? (and set the key as public final static to used it in `Activity2`) PS :Github is not a library of working code but a repository that could hold anything, working or not.

Comment: @AxelH I found the solution. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Since from your code i can see you're storing step counts in shared preference. so if you're moving to another activity. just before writing intent for new activity. set  your total step count to zero there

SharedPreferenceManager.singleton().save(Initial_Count_Key,0);

and then move onto other activity. that way when you come back to this activity yui will initialize your UI i.e. your step count UI from this preference value